# Many errors sending push notification with the Apigee console

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, apigee

We have an iOS app which is able to receive push notification through the Apigee SDK.

The push notifications are sent by using the Apigee admin console.

Within the console, we configured both dev and prod environments. The prod environment is used for the app published in the App Store. In both cases, the push notifications are well received by our iPhone devices.

However, my question is about the status displayed in the Message History section of the Apigee console.

In the case of the dev notifier, the console display the message : Finished (with errors) with by example, a total sent of 660 for a total errors of 1318.
I don't well understand these figures and I don't know where they are documented.
Is the total sent figure for the number of devices to which the push is sent? However, we don't have as many devices with the dev app version installed

The devices we have with the dev app version installed have well received the push as expected so why are there as many errors?
The detail of the error message is: "INVALID_TOKEN: Failed sending notification."

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

We have a bug where statistics get calculated inaccurately if you have errors from the Apns service since they come back asynchronously.

Invalid Token usually means the device is not registered with the apple push notifications service anymore.